# Как открыть https сайты через iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

не отображвется сайты использующие протокол https в iframe
например:

```
<iframe src="https://site.com/"></iframe>
```

почему не открываются и как обойти?

Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ спасибо, я знаю как отмечать. Отметить всегда успею, мне очень важно получить хотябы намеки на решения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разработчик любого сайта может запретить встраивание его во фрейм в популярных браузеров, используя заголовки `X-Frame-Options` или `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors ...`.

Это сделано для предотвращения Click-though/ClickJacking аттак (прокликивания). Пример такой атаки:

- Злой хакер встраивает во фрейм своего сайта eBay с кнопкой "Купить сейчас".
- Поверх ложит прокликиваемый оверлей с картинкой (кликни котику по носу!) так, чтобы нос котика попадал точно на кнопку.
- Заманивает жертву на сайт и ждет.

Считается хорошим тоном запрещать встраивание своего сайта/приложения, кроме случаев, когда это реально необходимо.

Гугл явно запретил встраивание google.com во все, кроме других страниц на google.com (`SAMEORIGIN`), так что встроить его в свой сайт не получится.

Comment: Это печально :(. альтернатива решений для этой задачи тоже нет?

Comment: @EmirMamashov если бы была - злоумышленники бы ей активно пользовались.

Answer (score 0):

Просто надо свой сайт тоже открывать по https.

Comment: а почему не открывается на обычном? можете обьянит по подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: @EmirMamashov, вероятно, политика безопасности браузера. Ну и ещё стоит проверить заголовки, разрешающие отображения этого конкретного сайта в iframe.

Comment: вы уверены что если поставлю ssl проблема будет решена? вы не проверяли?

Comment: @EmirMamashov, не проверял. Кстати, браузер же должен в консоль писать причину отказа.

Comment: да вот что он пишет: Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: @EmirMamashov, "because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'" - гугл вообще нельзя показывать в iframe'е.